# Нахождение крайних точек фигур на Android

Tags: java, android

StackOverflow. Встречал ли кто-нибудь из вас работающий алгоритм нахождения пробелов между контурами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, картинка может выглядеть так. Нужно найти координаты отмеченных крайних точек. Изображения по умолчанию черно-белые. Толщина линий может быть разной. То есть с толщиной в пиксель всё было бы проще.

Я пробовал перебирать все точки битмапа, проверять на чёрный цвет, но дальше затык. как определить, что точка крайняя? В смысле программно.

Может как-то разделить все массивы точек на разные массивы, где каждый массив точек отдельная фигура, а затем найти конечные значения? но если толщина линии 5 пикселей, то как определить, какая именно точка крайняя?

Всю голову уже сломал.

Comment: А если найти чёрную точку, а потом от неё сделать поиск в ширину или глубину? А там дальше вроде как не сложно будет крайнюю точку найти. upd. хотя с линиями в 1 пиксель будут проблемы

Comment: Drawn Raccoon, как раз с толщиной в 1 пиксель всё просто - проверяешь всех восьмерых соседей и всё. если у точки два соседа - она в центре, если один - конечная.